# change the values of a polars Dataframe column

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I am new to `polars` library and I want to find the most efficient way for the following:

I have the `DataFrame`

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'col 1': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]]})
```

and I want to change every list into a list of pairs of consecutive elements. For example the lists of the first and second rows will turn into

```
[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)] 
[(11,12),(13,14),(15,16)]
```

respectively.

A way to transform each list is with the following code

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[e for e in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]
```

I know that polars works best with the Expression API. Can I do it utilizing the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another subtle way to do it, since it's grouping consecutive values: we're changing the dimensions of the list from 6x1 to 3x2. Thus, a [`reshape`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.reshape.html) of the underlying Series per row with `arr.eval`:

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col('col 1').arr.eval(pl.element().reshape((-1, 2))))
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌────────────────────────────────┐
│ col 1                          │
│ ---                            │
│ list[list[i64]]                │
╞════════════════════════════════╡
│ [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]       │
│ [[11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16]] │
│ [[21, 22], [23, 24], [25, 26]] │
└────────────────────────────────┘
```